# COUNTIFS SUMIFS within Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, countif, sumifs

I want to add few columns within Power Query/ Power Pivot using COUNTIFS.  Within excel sheet the formula is  this
=COUNTIFS('KPI.03 Feeder'!H:H,1,'KPI.03 Feeder'!P:P,'KPI-03'!A3,'KPI.03 Feeder'!K:K,"")

The current sheet is KPI-03 and the other sheet is KPI.03 Feeder.  I know one can use calculate and AllExcept functions together but here I am doing multiple countifs and criteria are also number 1 for the first condition.  I am not sure how to implement these COUNTIFS in Power Pivot.

There is this SUMIFS function I want solution on
=SUMIF('KPI.03 Feeder'!$H:$H,1,'KPI.03 Feeder'!R:R)

Comment: So, what happened? what makes the results incorrect? What else did you try?

Comment: These formulas works fine on the Excel spreadsheet, I want to perform these calculations within PowerPivot (Data Model) area.

Comment: For COUNTIFS I worked out how to do the first COUNTIF condition is to write this calculate function.  =CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]), FILTER(KPI3FeederRaw,KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]=1)) where Current/Close Priority is H column.  I don't know how to include other COUNTIFS conditions within the same Add new column area of Power Pivot.

Comment: To add the 2nd COUNTIFS condition I wrote these 2 Calculate functions and combined them using &&  =CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]), FILTER(KPI3FeederRaw,KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]=1)) && CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Graph Month Open]), FILTER('KPI-03','KPI-03'[Month]))  This gives me result TRUE instead of a number.  If I use just one & then it concatenates both the calculate outputs.

Comment: && is equivalent to AND(), you want to show 2 values in the same formula? WHY? just use 2, but if you really must... TEXT(CALCULATE())&" "&TEXT(CALCULATE())

Comment: No I don’t want to show 2 values.  I want to do COUNTIFS with 3 different conditions and calculate the count based on that.

Comment: I am using this countif within Power Pivot (Data Model) area.  I don't need Text(Calculate).  Currently I am using this formula and it concatenates output of both Calculate function. =CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]), FILTER(KPI3FeederRaw,KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]=1)) & CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Graph Month Open]), FILTER('KPI3FeederRaw', KPI3FeederRaw[Graph Month Open] = 'KPI-03'[Month]))  I dont want concatenation of it, I need to apply those 2 conditions to the data model.

Comment: They are working fine one by one, but I don't know how to apply all 3 conditions at the same time.  The following code appends the result of each of the 3 calculate function.  Please someone explain me how to apply them altogether. =CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]), FILTER(KPI3FeederRaw,KPI3FeederRaw[Current/Closed Priority]=1)) & CALCULATE(COUNTA(KPI3FeederRaw[Graph Month Open]), FILTER('KPI3FeederRaw', KPI3FeederRaw[Graph Month Open] = 'KPI-03'[Month])) &  CALCULATE(COUNTBLANK(KPI3FeederRaw[Date Closed]), FILTER(KPI3FeederRaw, ISBLANK(KPI3FeederRaw[Date Closed])))